# Возможно ли индексировать коллекцию с индексами больше 3 млрд?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Пример рабочего кода:

```
declare
  type a is table of number index by pls_integer;
  b a;
begin
  b(1) := 5;
end;
```

Но тогда нельзя написать `b(3000000000)`, т.к. этот индекс далеко за пределами `pls_integer`, а нужно использовать больше 2.1 млрд. Можно переделать в `index by varchar2`, но это повышает время выполнения запросов процентов на 30.

`index by number` не работает:

```
declare
  type a is table of number index by number;
  b a;
begin
  b(1) := 5;
end;
```

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 2, column 13:
> PLS-00315: Implementation restriction: unsupported table index type

Есть ли путь использовать числовую индексацию больше 2.1млрд?

Элементов в массиве при этом не так много.

Comment: не известно, что скрывается за индексами, но может существует способ их однозначно отобразить на меньшее множество чисел? и тогда проблема сама по себе уйдет

Comment: Да, там используются id из таблицы в качестве индекса. Сейчас как самое разумное и быстрое решение - заменил на varchar2. Оно даже работает (видимо, не явно преобразуется в строку и обратно, что и замедляет запрос). Но думается мне, что делать геттер (по id возвращал бы index), то сильно легче не станет. id тоже никак не поменять, конечно, в боевой то базе.

Comment: A какая нужда использовать именно ассоциативную коллекцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, нельзя превысить лимит `BINARY_INTEGER|PLS_INTEGER` (-2147483648 до  2147483647).

Ркомендуемый обходной путь решения - [преобразование в `VARCHAR2`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/collection-variable.html#GUID-89A1863C-65A1-40CF-9392-86E9FDC21BE9) с функцией `TO_CHAR`:

> You can populate an element of the associative array with a value of any type that can be converted to VARCHAR2 with the TO_CHAR function

Так будет самое эффективное решение:

```
declare 
    type numlist is table of number index by varchar (12);
    idx number := 3e9; 
    nl numlist;
begin
    nl(to_char (idx)) := idx;
    dbms_output.put_line ('nl('||idx||') = '||nl(to_char (idx)));
end;
/

nl(3000000000) = 3000000000
```

Comment: Можно to_char не писать в индексе - он сам не явно приведет (я так в вопросе, в общем-то написал). Беда только, что так процесс происходит в 5 раз дольше (просто в цикле заполнил один и другой массив на 5млн элементов). При этом между varchar2(12) и varchar2(32000) нет никакой разницы. Но деваться, похоже, особо некуда.

Comment: Писать нужно по простой причине - явное всегда лучше не явного. Проседание в производительности будет, и от этого никуда недется. Другие решения будут ещё медленней. Если влезет в 4,2 млрд., то можно задействовать негативную часть, преобразование будет быстрее, но 5 млрд. уже не влезет.  Как вы написали - _Элементов в массиве не так много_, так что решение с varchar2 самое простое и самое эффективное.